# Rotating a point around another point

Tags: c++, math, rotation

I'm trying to rotate one point around a central point by an angle - standard problem. I've seen lots of posts about this but I can't get my implementation to work:

```
    void Point::Rotate(const Point Pivot, const float Angle)
    {
        if (Angle == 0)
            return;

        float s = sin(Angle);
        float c = cos(Angle);

        x -= Pivot.x;
        y -= Pivot.y;

        x = (x * c) - (y * s) + Pivot.x;
        y = (x * s) + (y * c) + Pivot.y;
    }
```

This is my code, the logic of which I've gleaned from numerous source, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953316/rotate-a-point-around-a-point-with-opencv), and [here](http://www.swissdelphicenter.com/torry/printcode.php?id=2094).

As far as I'm aware, it should work. However, when I apply it to rotating for example, the point (0, 100) by 90 degrees (Pi/2 is given to the function) around (0, 0), the rotated point is apparently at (-100, -100); 100px below where it should be.

When trying to draw a circle (36 points) - it creates a vague heart shape. It looks like a graph I saw that I think was in polar coordinates - do I need to convert my point to Cartesian or something?

Can anyone spot anything wrong with my code?

Edit: Sorry, this function is a member function to a Point class - `x` and `y` are the member variables :/

Comment: What value of `x` is being used in the final line?

Comment: I think you have missed my point!  The final line uses a value of `x`; where is that value calculated?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's the current x position - the member variable. Not sure how else to explain it?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Oh, right >.< I'm an idiot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, but you're modifying `x` in the next-to-last line, meaning that the value of that coordinate fed into the `y` calculation is incorrect!

Instead, use temporary variables for the new `x` and `y` and then add the `Pivot` coordinates on afterwards:

```
double nx = (x * c) - (y * s);
double ny = (x * s) + (y * c);

x = nx + Pivot.x;
y = ny + Pivot.y;
```